# How to use single instance of AVAudioPlayers for playing multiple songs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to play multiple songs with single object of AVAudioplayer, I put songs List in scrollview, when user tap on list player view is open but when user go back for other song player play both songs simanteniosly . what I Can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to have `AVAudioplayer` as a kind of singleton. There are different ways of doing so. You "may" want to add it as an instance variable to your app delegate, but you could also want to create a new singleton object around it.

You should check out this great post on singletons and top level data: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

EDIT:
I'll give you an example on how to access it if it's a property (`audioPlayer`) of you app delegate.

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
AVAudioplayer *myOneAndOnlyPlayer = appDelegate.audioPlayer;
```

You have to create the ivar & property declaration in you app delegate and create the instance of `ACAudioplayer` in `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Comment: actually how i define our avaudioplayer object in appdelegate file
and how it use in our controller

Comment: hello sir i am very new in iphone i work with ajeet.you r right i think my problem is solved if i define our player in app delegate
so please tell me how i implement this.